# How to plot this dataframe to a animated plotly map by years?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, maps, choropleth

I have to do a plotly map with this dataframe

```
    country 2011    2012    2013    2014    2015    2016    Alpha-2 code    Alpha-3 code    Numeric code    ISO 3166-2
    0   Argentina   0   0   0   0   0   1   AR  ARG 32  ISO 3166-2:AR
    1   Australia   7   21  19  19  20  31  AU  AUS 36  ISO 3166-2:AU
    2   Austria 2   5   6   6   5   7   AT  AUT 40  ISO 3166-2:AT
    3   Bangladesh  0   0   0   0   0   1   BD  BGD 50  ISO 3166-2:BD
    4   Belarus 0   0   0   0   0   1   BY  BLR 112 ISO 3166-2:BY
    5   Belgium 2   7   7   7   7   7   BE  BEL 56  ISO 3166-2:BE
    6   Brazil  0   2   2   2   2   17  BR  BRA 76  ISO 3166-2:BR
    7   Canada  9   18  19  19  18  25  CA  CAN 124 ISO 3166-2:CA
    8   Chile   0   1   0   0   1   6   CL  CHL 152 ISO 3166-2:CL
    9   China   6   10  9   10  11  37  CN  CHN 156 ISO 3166-2:CN
    10  Colombia    0   0   1   1   1   2   CO  COL 170 ISO 3166-2:CO
```

I tried to do this but i don't know what to put in "animation frame" and "color". Thank you

```
fig = px.choropleth(theiso, locations='Alpha-3 code', color=['2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016'], 
                        hover_name="country",scope='world', animation_frame =['2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016'])
    
    fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]["frame"]["duration"] = 2000
    
    fig.update_geos(visible=False, resolution=50, scope="world",
        showcountries=True, countrycolor="Black")
    
    fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":25,"l":0,"b":0},title="Numero di università totali per paese")
    fig.show()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) first to unpivot your `df` from wide to long format.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

theiso = theiso.melt(id_vars=['country','Alpha-3 code'], 
                     value_vars=['2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016'], 
                     var_name='Year', value_name='Numero di università')

# add `range_color` with a stable `min` (e.g. 0) and `max` (e.g. 40)
fig = px.choropleth(theiso, locations='Alpha-3 code', hover_name="country", 
                    color='Numero di università', scope='world', 
                    animation_frame ='Year', range_color=(0,40))

fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]["frame"]["duration"] = 2000

fig.update_geos(visible=False, resolution=50, scope="world",
    showcountries=True, countrycolor="Black")

fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":25,"l":0,"b":0}, 
                  title="Numero di università totali per paese")
fig.show()
```

Result:

[image: px_choropleth]